# Open new window on submit

Tags: javascript, html

i have a question in html. I already wrote my code but now I want to open a new window after someone clicked the submit button and in this new window the text he or she entered shall be displayed.

```
<html>
<body>
<font face="Arial,Helvetica">Hello! 
</body>  
<p><label for="vname">Tell me something:
<input type="text" id="vname" name="vname">
    </font> 
<body>
</p>
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myAlert()">
    </html>
```

Comment: Does it have to be on a different page? It's a lot easier to simply wipe the form page (make it blank), and then display the text.

Comment: Yes that would also be okay! But how could i do that?

Comment: Check my answer, and if it helped, please accept it

Comment: First, you don't have a `form` element, so an `input type=submit` isn't going to get you very far. Second, you can't close the `body` and then reopen it. You should brush up on your HTML first.

Comment: I edited my answer- check it out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, you should use a `<form>`. Otherwise, the `<input type="submit">` doesn't really do anything. Once you have that, use `window.open()`.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <label for="vname">Tell me something:
    <input type="text" id="vname" name="vname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myAlert()">
</form>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function myAlert() {
    var results = window.open();
    var vname = document.getElementById("vname").value;
    results.document.write(vname);
}
```

Basically, the JS gets the value of the input, opens a new page, and then uses `document.write` to display the results.

## Original answer

(The asker requested I put this version of my answer back up)

```
<form onsubmit="myAlert(); return false">
    <label for="vname">Tell me something:
    <input type="text" id="vname" name="vname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function myAlert() {
    var vname = document.getElementById("vname").value;
    document.write(vname);
}
```

Comment: `document.write` is ancient and will cause the ENTIRE page to be removed and instead just the new value will be written.  The correct approach would be to get a DOM reference to an element (probably initially empty) and then write content to that.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but you may also know how i could open a new window displaying the text ?

Comment: Yes- give me a second, and I'll get you that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus- I realize that. I personally believe that InnerHTML would work much better, but the OA specifically asked for a blank page with the input value

Comment: @MrPetroleum- I added the code to have it open in a new page.

Comment: @Zack105 Yes thank you but unfortunately there is no input field anymore it just opens a new window. I try to figure out what is missing but I don't know..

Comment: @MrPetroleum- I'm a bit confused here... Do you want the input field to be on the first page, or the new one?

Comment: @Zack105 I wanted the entered text to be displayed in the new window. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @Zack105 But i really liked the version with the wipe as you suggest at the beginning do you mind put it online again. Thank you in advance

Comment: @MrPetroleum- I put it back up, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This code will get you to open a new window and fill it in with form values

```
function myAlert() {
    var NewWindow= window.open();
    var nameValue = document.getElementById("vname").value;
    NewWindow.document.write("<p>Some text followed by form value </p>"+  nameValue );
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! But unfortunately I only get a blank window. So there is no input field anymore..

Comment: here is the working code pen link ': http://codepen.io/saa93/pen/BQyrNN

Comment: i don't know why but i get a blank window

Comment: I was testing in different browsers to see what could have went wrong on ur end. Why wasn't it coming up earlier ?

Comment: Actually I don't know i think i did something wrong but now its works fine

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you are missing. You need to include a form and prevent the form from sending. Here it is an example to get you going in the right direction!

```js
(function(){
 var f, s, w;
 
 f = document.forms.submit;
 
 f.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  s = "Name: ";
  s += f.name.value;
  s += "<br/>";
  s += "Last Name: ";
  s += f.last.value;
  
  w = window.open();
  w.document.write(s);
 });
}());
```

```html
<form  id="submit">
 <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"/>
 <input type="text" id="last" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```